# Spawning a process in elixir

Tags: elixir, spawn

I spawned a process in elixir using two ways :

```
defmodule Second do
   def called do
     raise "oops" 
   end

end

spawn(Second.called)
** (RuntimeError) oops
second.exs:3: Second.called/0

 spawn(Second,:called,[])
 #PID<0.89.0>
 iex(2)> 17:42:40.999 [error] Process #PID<0.89.0> raised an exception
 ** (RuntimeError) oops
```

What is the difference in the two methods ? Why is only the  second one returning a process id and not the first one ? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

In the first one you're calling `Second.called` directly and that raises so the `spawn` never gets called. The second version will call `spawn` and the new process will call `Second.called` with no args which then raises.

Answer (score 2):

In the first example, the code is blowing up before getting to the actual `spawn`. I imagine that what you wanted to do is `spawn(&Second.called/0)`, which will return the same error as the second example.